# CakePHP 2.x: working with an existing database that does not follow the naming conventions

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am new to CakePHP 2.x. What would be the best solution for working with an existing database that does not follow the naming conventions?

My current task requirements:

1. Existing database contains a lot of tables (more than 20)
2. My task requires read and save operations.
3. The solution makes maintenance more manageable in the future.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ideally, if you're just starting, you'd start with version 4.x, as 2.x is long since abandoned.

Comment: The [useTable](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/models/model-attributes.html#usetable) configuration is how you tell CakePHP 2.0 to use a non-standard table name.